# Xamarin IOs, What are the string values to pass into UIFontMetrics.GetMetrics method for the textStyle parameter?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, dynamictype

I'm having a Xamarin.IOs project. I need to use dynamic type fonts in my application.

I have followed [this tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/245/) in doing so. The tutorial is in in swift I guess. And for the code segment,

```
label.Font = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .title1).ScaledFont(for: customFont)
```

in the tutorial, the equivalent Xamarin.IOs C# code is,

```
label.Font = UIFontMetrics.GetMetrics(textStyle: <string_value>).GetScaledFont(customFont);
```

But what are the values can I use for `<string_value>` of `textStyle`?

I have tried,

- `"title 1"`
- `"title1"`
- `".title1"`
- `".title 1"`
- `"UIFontTextStyleTitle1"`
- `"PreferredTitle1"`

but non helped.

What string values does `UIFontMetrics.GetMetrics()` accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this,

### Way 1:

```
UIFontMetrics.GetMetrics(UIFontDescriptor.PreferredTitle1.TextStyle).GetScaledFont(customFont);
```

The text style's string values can be taken from the `TextStyle` property of `UIFontDescriptor` text style properties,

```
UIFontDescriptor.PreferredTitle1.TextStyle
```

### Way 2:

```
UIFontMetrics.GetMetrics(UIFontTextStyle.Title1.GetConstant()).GetScaledFont(customFont);
```

The text style's string values can be taken from the `GetConstant()` extension method of `UIFontTextStyle` text style properties,

```
UIFontTextStyle.Title1.GetConstant()
```

One of these would be much better than entering string values directly

Comment: I'm surprised Xamarin didn't create the constants for this. Sigh, Xamarin.